# How to copy files using telnet from the remote pc to my pc

Tags: telnet

For our school project, a friend and I have been assigned the task of finding a way to to transfer files from computer to computer via telnet. Does anyone know of a simple set of commands, or a GUI tool, by which to do so?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using Windows or Linux or OSX? You really shouldn't be using telnet to transfer files. Try SFTP, or FTP if you don't care about people snooping through the passwords used to connect. I've always found Filezilla's FTP client and server to work well enough.

Comment: Telnet isnt really the best way to transfer files. If you want to transfer files across command line, look into ssh and scp.

Comment: This problem was solved thirty years ago with the invention of FTP, and has been solved much more reliably since with SCP, rsync, and any number of other protocols. Those are excellent wheels and quite round; attempting to reinvent them is inadvisable in the extreme.

Comment: @AaronMiller  I don't think you read the whole thing, it was assigned to him as a project, it has to be through telnet, it's probably a beginners class on the history of file transfer protocols.

Comment: @user88311 I did read the whole thing, and it doesn't contain enough information to be certain that the requirement includes using the telnet protocol specifically. If not, I'd recommend using anything else. If so, it's time to start writing code that can open a telnet socket to the target machine, use `cat` or equivalent to dump the text of the target file across the socket, and capture the result into a similarly named file on the originating host.

Comment: can you use netcat instead? google for "netcat tarpipe" to find out how

Answer (score 2):

If the client side supports logging, you could simply run a utility on the remote system to "uuencode" the file and output to `stdout`.  You can then pull the file from the log and "uudecode" it locally.  (PuTTY is a great telnet client and supports logging, I'm sure the built-in Windows Hyperterminal does as well.)

[An answer on the Server Fault website](https://serverfault.com/questions/5729/file-transfer-using-telnet) suggests [C-Kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ck90.html).  I've never used it - it looks like it might work over an existing network connection like Telnet rather than only via serial.

Of course if you don't have an absolutely strict requirement to use the Telnet protocol to transfer the file, there's about thousand better ways to transfer files.  Look into `nc` (netcat).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your telnet client - if you have one which supports x/y/zmodem emulation might be to use one of the old file transfer protocols (like Xmodem or zmodem).  (look for an sz or lrzsz package on the server side).  Then just sz (filename) on the server side.